# Creating permissions rules with ACF repeater field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a set of permission rules for a custom post type depending on user infos but I don't see how to wp query my posts with theses infos.

I've created a repeater field which allow me to select:

- The user_meta key
- The comparison operator (AND or OR)
- The value of the user_meta key

Here is a screenshot to show you how I've done it:
[image]
The main box is for **OR** permissions and each box in it for **AND** permissions.

Now I wanted to query my posts if the rules matched or if there is the repeater field is empty but I can't get my head around it...

Here is an exemple of what the repeater field returns:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [ressource_regles_et] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [ressource_permission_name] => le-centre
        [ressource_permission_rule] => is
        [ressource_permission_value_fonction] => Array
          (
          )

        [ressource_permission_value_service] => Array
          (
          )

        [ressource_permission_value_centre] => baudricourt
      )

      [1] => Array
      (
        [ressource_permission_name] => le-centre
        [ressource_permission_rule] => is
        [ressource_permission_value_fonction] => Array
          (
          )

        [ressource_permission_value_service] => Array
          (
          )

        [ressource_permission_value_centre] => curial
      )

    )

  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [ressource_regles_et] => Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [ressource_permission_name] => la-fonction
        [ressource_permission_rule] => is-not
        [ressource_permission_value_fonction] => president-e
        [ressource_permission_value_service] => Array
          (
          )

        [ressource_permission_value_centre] => Array
          (
          )

      )

    )

  )

)
```

Each key indexed first level array is for an **OR** permission and each array inside `[ressource_regles_et]` is for and **AND** permission.

Now I know how to apply my rules after having queried all the posts but I'd like to get the rules in `WP_Query` so that I can use Wordpress builtin pagination system.

Any ideas on how to you would do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yikes, those are going to be some expensive queries. Have you thought about creating a custom taxonomy (or taxonomies) instead to reduce the overhead?

Comment: I know... I thought about custom taxonomies but it would be much less flexible.